# How to plot a concave set in R?

Tags: r, segment, concave

I have one question with the 'curve' function in R. Maybe it's not the best way to implement my idea, but here we go.

I was trying to plot a function which is composed of several segments. The difference is on the slope. Just to illustrate, the first piece is something like "y = 1300 - 3.83*x" for [0,10]. The next segment, "y = 1300-4.41*t" would be on [11,20] and so on according to the code below.

```
    seg1 <- function(t) 1300-3.83*t
    curve(seg1, 0, 10, n=1000,xlim=c(0,150),ylim=c(0,1400))
    seg2 <- function(t) 1300-4.41*t
    curve(seg2, 10,20,n=1000,add=TRUE)
    seg3 <- function(t) 1300-5.83*t
    curve(seg3, 20,30,n=4000, add=TRUE)
    seg4 <- function(t) 1300-6.71*t
    curve(seg4, 30,50,n=16000,add=TRUE)
    seg5 <- function(t) 1300-7.71*t
    curve(seg5, 50,100,n=10000,add=TRUE)
    seg6 <- function(t) 1300-8.87*t
    curve(seg6,100,150,n=9000,add=TRUE)
```

The resulting plot, however, is full of blank spaces.I couldn't appendix it here, but I would expect something like a concave set, not a lot of segments with blank spaces among them. It should be connected. Maybe this is not the best way to plot a function with discontinuities in R.

Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: take a look at `?stepfun`

Comment: I do not think the request is at all clear. You have a discontinuous function and you what to do ... what exactly? Are you trying to reinvent splines? Or do you just want to connect some points (for which the `lines` function would be one possibility.)

Comment: Ok, I am not sure if it is splines. My problem is an economic one. I am trying to generate a budget constraint with discontinuities.

Comment: So the problem is not really a plotting problem at all? Its a function definitonal issue?

Answer (score 0):

How about generating points instead of using `curve`?

```
seg1 <- function(t) 1300-3.83*t
seg2 <- function(t) 1300-4.41*t
seg3 <- function(t) 1300-5.83*t
seg4 <- function(t) 1300-6.71*t
seg5 <- function(t) 1300-7.71*t
seg6 <- function(t) 1300-8.87*t

step <- 0.5 # Smaller for better look but slower to plot
y <- c(seg1(seq(0,10,step)),
       seg2(seq(10,20,step)),
       seg3(seq(20,30,step)),
       seg4(seq(30,50,step)),
       seg5(seq(50,100,step)),
       seg6(seq(100,150,step)))
plot(y, type='l', xlim=c(0,150), ylim=c(0,1400))
```

**EDIT:**

Your post is wrong, then, but if I am understanding your comment right, what you need to do is to change the `from` and `to` in you code to the same number:

```
seg1 <- function(t) 1300-3.83*t
seg2 <- function(t) 1300-4.41*t
seg3 <- function(t) 1300-5.83*t
seg4 <- function(t) 1300-6.71*t
seg5 <- function(t) 1300-7.71*t
seg6 <- function(t) 1300-8.87*t

curve(seg1, 0, 150, n=1000,xlim=c(0,150),ylim=c(0,1400))
curve(seg2, 0,150,n=1000,add=TRUE)
curve(seg3, 0,150,n=1000, add=TRUE)
curve(seg4, 0,150,n=1000,add=TRUE)
curve(seg5, 0,150,n=1000,add=TRUE)
curve(seg6, 0,150,n=1000,add=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still can't get why the plot method give me the 'steps'. It should be just an intersection point with changing slopes.

Comment: There you go, edited it. If what you want is a convex set, you have your curves quite wrong though...

Comment: Yes, Julius pointed to my typo. I will test it and I come back here soon :)

Answer (score 0):

Another but more flexible way to generate points:

```
segments <- mget(paste0("seg", 1:6)) # A list of functions

ll <- c(0, 10, 20, 30, 50, 100) # Lower limits
ul <- c(10, 20, 30, 50, 100, 150) # Upper limits
k <- length(ll) # Number of segments
n <- 100 # Points per each segment

myfun <- function(ll, ul, n)
  c(mapply(function(s, l, u) s(seq(l, u, length = n)), segments, ll, ul))

plot(y = myfun(ll, ul, n), x = seq(ll[1], ul[k], length = n * k), type = 'l')
```

Comment: Thank you Julius, your method seems to work well, but still there are the vertical connection between two lines. Isn't this strange?

Comment: Actually, your method generated the best plot until now. Again, thank you.

Comment: @Claudio, according to your example code, there should be vertical connections. However, in the text you mention [11,20] instead of [10,20], so if that is what you want, you should change `ll` accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, Julius. I think I typed wrongly in the first post. The right is 11. Yes. I have to do this.